# sqlsrv_query отваливается при выполнении хранимой процедуры

Tags: sql-server, sqlsrv

использую Microsoft SQL Server Driver для PHP.
Соотвественно моё субд MS SQL Server.
Итак , делаю подключение что-то вроде этого, тут без проблем:

```
$serverName = "BUHSERVER"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"limdb", "UID"=>"SYSADM", "PWD"=>"limcorp", "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>1);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

в SQL строке делаю 'exec te 10' и выполняю sqlsrv_query
причем хранимая процедура "te" содержит в своем теле insert into и далее делает выборку вот так выглядит te:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[te] (@n numeric(10))
as
insert into SPK_te values (@n)
exec tei2 200  
--return 0
go
ALTER proc [dbo].[tei2] (@n numeric(10))
as
select 'test' as hhh
```

так вот похоже на инсерте в хранимке te функция sqlsrv_query отваливается и завершает выполнение скрипта. что неправильно, должна ещё отработать выборка. то есть выдать должен test
В чем может быть дело ?

Comment: одно единственное. я упростил свою проблему , чтобы не грузить вас , поэтому сделал элементарную табличку и элементарные хранимки. разумеется и инсерт голый, если я запущу в менеджмент студио или если запущу exec te 10 . Тогда всё работает корректно. А если я коменчу инсерт в хранимке te тогда нормально получаю ответ 'test' в php скрипте . То есть ощущение , что insert даёт какой-то ненужный ответ при котором sqlsrv_query отваливается.

Comment: Вопрос 1 - а запись со значением 10 в таблицу попадает или нет? если нет - то включи dirty reads и посмотри, есть ли она в таблице, когда выполнение подвисло. Вопрос 2 - если вместо `exec tei2 200` вставить SELECT - всё нормально? а если не вместо, а перед - то он отрабатывает?

Comment: @Akina
прикол в том , что похоже SQL процедуры отрабатывают нормально в том числе и инсерт, вот  только ответ не дают или пхп-шка его не принимает. Более того , если я даже инсерт добавлю и в хранимку tei2 он тоже отработает . Но во всех этих случаях ответ вызванный ```select 'test' as hhh``` отсутствует - и это проблема.

Comment: Ммм.. а метод вызова-выполнения - он вообще умеет принимать мультирекордсет, состоящий из статусов и наборов записей одновременно?

Comment: №1 запись попадает. №2 - да так отработает

Comment: @Akina вот и я не знаю. а как быть ? )

Comment: А как выполняешь? через sqlsrv_execute? и потом выгребаешь результаты через sqlsrv_next_result?

Comment: sqlsrv_query , sqlsrv_fetch_array

Comment: Приплыли... sqlsrv_query выполняет ОДИН запрос и принимает ОДИН набор данных. Вот, как только сервер пытается в него воткнуть второй набор, ему и плохеет.

Comment: а как с ней работать ? ```$this->stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($this->conn, "select ? as field", array(0));
$result = sqlsrv_execute($this->stmt);
if (!$result) return;
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
print_r($row);
``` вообще выдаёт вот чо Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\WWW\www\rpt_all_equip.php on line 52 а хотелось бы чтобы выдал результат с нулём (0)

Comment: А вот не надо методов научного тыка. Изучи нормально документацию и примеры.  Там всё есть.

Comment: спасибо. разобрался.

Comment: @Akina а ещё можно вопрос ? ))) скажите , а можно наш php заставить скрипт игнорить ошибки??? скажем если хранимой процедуре в SQL-запросе у нас произойдет деление на ноль ? понимаю глупый вопрос, ведь лучше подправить и исключить ошибки , но это дер*мище писал не я и править не хочу.

Comment: Не спрашивайте меня за PHP - не владею.

Comment: @Akina да я бы не сказал, что не владеете. всё же помогли. вот я вот не владею. эх, ну ладно.

Comment: Не забывайте добавлять в процедуры команду `SET NOCOUNT ON;`. Зачастую информация о количестве обработанных строк может порождать подобные проблемы

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin спасибо. поставлю SET NOCOUNT ON; а можно ли при помощи sqlsrv_execute,  sqlsrv_next_result обработать ответ от хранимой процедуры игнорируя сообщения об ошибках таких как деление на ноль ?

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin ```ALTER proc [dbo].[te] (@n numeric(10))
as
declare @t numeric(10)
select @t = 5/0
insert into SPK_te values (@n) select 'test' as hhh``` вот смотрите в хп умышленное деление на ноль, однако последний селект отрабатывается. возможно ли каким-то образом отключить эту ругань ? чтобы пхп не реагировал